# Aligning a rightarrow with path between images in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know if there is a better way to align the right arrow between Fig 1 and Fig 2. Currently I was able to do it with `node[right=2cm]`.

I wonder why I wasn't able to use the `node[midway]` (this is what worked for Fig 2 and Fig 3). I thought that this would have placed the right arrow "in the middle of Fig1 and Fig 2"

[image]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,14pt, letterpaper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=R]
 \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
 \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
 \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
 \draw 
   (A) -- 
   node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
   node[right] {?} (C) -- 
   node[below] {?} 
   (A);
 \draw 
   (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
 \end{scope}
   \path (R) -- (M) node[right=2cm, scale=1.4]{$\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}$};
 \node[anchor=north,text width=6cm,align=center] at (R.south) {\captionof{figure}{Caption 1}};

 \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,local bounding box=M]
 \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
 \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
 \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
 \draw 
   (A) -- 
   node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
   node[right] {x} (C) -- 
   node[below] {1} 
   (A);
 \draw 
   (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=north,text width=6cm,align=center] at (M.south) {\captionof{figure}{Caption 2}};
 \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm,local bounding box=R]
 \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
 \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
 \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
 \draw 
   (A) -- 
   node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
   node[right] {1} (C) -- 
   node[below] {x} 
   (A);
 \draw 
   (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
 \end{scope}
 \path (M) -- (R) node[midway,scale=1.4]{$\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}$};
 \draw[red,thick] (R.north west)  -- (R.south east)
  (R.north east)  -- (R.south west);
 \node[anchor=north,text width=6cm,align=center] at (R.south) {\captionof{figure}{Caption 3}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

edit: uncentered
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the `local bounding box`es unique names and repeat what you've done on the right.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,14pt, letterpaper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=L]
 \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
 \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
 \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
 \draw 
   (A) -- 
   node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
   node[right] {?} (C) -- 
   node[below] {?} 
   (A);
 \draw 
   (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=north,text width=6cm,align=center] at (L.south) {\captionof{figure}{Caption 1}};

 \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,local bounding box=M]
 \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
 \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
 \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
 \draw 
   (A) -- 
   node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
   node[right] {x} (C) -- 
   node[below] {1} 
   (A);
 \draw 
   (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=north,text width=6cm,align=center] at (M.south) {\captionof{figure}{Caption 2}};
 \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm,local bounding box=R]
 \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
 \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
 \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
 \draw 
   (A) -- 
   node[midway,above left=0pt] {$\sqrt{1+x^2}$} (B) --
   node[right] {1} (C) -- 
   node[below] {x} 
   (A);
 \draw 
   (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
 \end{scope}
 \path (L) -- (M) node[midway,scale=1.4]{$\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}$};
 \path (M) -- (R) node[midway,scale=1.4]{$\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}$};
 \draw[red,thick] (R.north west)  -- (R.south east)
  (R.north east)  -- (R.south west);
 \node[anchor=north,text width=6cm,align=center] at (R.south) {\captionof{figure}{Caption 3}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you advise how to center the image? It isn't showing up quite straight for me, not sure if you are seeing the same thing or not. Why isn't `\centering` centering the figure properly? I updated main post with a pic

Comment: @EvanKim It is not centered because your figure is too wide for the current settings of your document. To see this, replace `\begin{document}` by `\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red] (current page text area.south west) rectangle
(current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}` which draws a frame around the text area. It shows that your figure overshoots at the right. So you might want to increase the width of the page and/or make the figure smaller.